# is it possible to override django's {{ }} for specific object?

Tags: python, django

E.g. if I print [Fraction](https://docs.python.org/2/library/fractions.html) object (by that I mean put {{ my_fraction }} in the template) I want it to print as an integer in the case of denominator=1 and as a fraction (e.g. simply a/b) otherwise.

What is the simplest/most elegant way to achieve this? Can I override what is rendered in the template if I use {{ object }}?

I know I could to it with the {% if %} statement, but that seems very unelegant to me (and also my HTML code would be mess)

Comment: Can you do the logic in the view?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. What I can do in my view is convert the fraction to integer, if denominator=1. But than {{ my_fraction }} will still render something like <fraction_object at ...>

Comment: You should write a custom filter https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-filters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [custom template filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-filters).

```
# e.g. in my_app/templatetags/fraction_tags.py

@register.filter
def pretty_fraction(value):
    if value.denominator == 1:
        return unicode(value.numerator)
    else:
        return unicode(value)
```

use it with:

```
{% load fraction_tags %}

{{ my_fraction|pretty_fraction }}
```

Comment: In this example, `value` would be `my_fraction`. The filter expects it to be a fraction. A filter can return HTML, but you have to mark it as safe, otherwise it will be escaped. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/custom-template-tags/#filters-and-auto-escaping

Comment: What about `fractions.Fraction(2, 2)` or even `fractions.Fraction(x, y)` where `x % y == 0`? Do those matter to you?

Answer (score 2):

`fractions.Fraction(1, 1)` already outputs 1 when used in string context

```
>>> fractions.Fraction(1, 1).__str__()
'1'
>>> fractions.Fraction(1, 1).__unicode__()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'Fraction' object has no attribute '__unicode__'
>>> fractions.Fraction(1, 1).__repr__()
'Fraction(1, 1)'
>>> unicode(fractions.Fraction(1,1))
u'1'
>>> str(fractions.Fraction(1,1))
'1'
```

Comment: good point. i'll probably use the custom template filter though, in case I decided to print something nicer than simply a/b

Answer (score 0):

Django templates when presented with an object simply outputs:

```
def __unicode__():
   return "something arbitrary"
```

You would need to monkey patch it onto the object (bad idea) if you specifically wanted to control the output. Instead you should use a filter, but then you get `{{object|format_fraction}}`.

```
@register.filter
def format_fraction(fraction):
  fraction.numerator if fraction.denominator == 1 else fraction
```

The alternative is that you inherit the fraction object into a `DjangoFraction` with an overriden `__unicode__` for output purposes, but that's a terrible idea.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for django template-tags, there are many [builtins](http://ttps://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/) but if you want something specific you can always [create custom one](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/custom-template-tags/)